# Can't paste items into directory if it is made by another user

Tags: permissions, samba, users, directory

I can't add documents to directories made by other users of my samba file server.  Say I'm user1, and there is another person user2.  If user2 makes a folder, and I (user1) try to add something to it, it says you don't have permission, but user2 can drop all the stuff he wants into it.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thats the dealing with the permission the user2 set. The folder was created by user2 so the rightful owner of that folder is user2 only.unless he gave the permissions to you , you can not view that.

**how can you access it ??**

well you can access that in two ways.

- If you are the root /admin user then you can directly access the folder by using your root power.
- ask him for the permissions.

There are no other ways legally.

Update

OP as you mentioned , If something there to deal with SAMBA , then you must look over `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

for example:

```
[music]
path = /home/shared/music
```

for that shared file If you made the permissions as

- read only = Yes  # only read only
- create mask = 0775  # this is the mask value as root can do anything , but users and others can read and execute can not write.
- writeable = Yes  # giving write permissions.

So everything to deal with sharing will be at samba configuration file. The path already gave you.

Comment: Both of them are my accounts(for now.  I have figured out it has to do with the samba not assigning the correct masks and "no owner" to new files and directories...Any fix for this? It works fine when I manually change the groups and masks after the file is made.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I seem to have gotten it.  I posted my finds for future reference to others.

Comment: what ever the mask you made thats very danger.

Comment: why?  Is 0777 not good?

Comment: This is a home server, so I'm not too worried about security, but would like to have it as good as possible.  Everybody needs to be able to read and write to everything too though.

Comment: @Icero there is no problem with 77 but the last 7 will let all others to access you share and thats a security risk. read here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: as in all other users?

Comment: @Icero yes thats what I am saying . look at the file permissions link I gave you in above comment.

Comment: trying to decipher it now.  I don't think it will be a problem for me, as I want all other users to have full access to my files.

Comment: full access means , just classify that. If you made 777 then other users also can read , write and execute. so decision is yours my friend.

Comment: I see now, so If I where to do 700, then only I could access the folder/files?

Comment: No you better do like 750 , :)

Answer (score -1):

It turns out I needed a force create mode = 0777 setting in my smb.conf along with a force directory mode = 0777.

It works just fine now.

Comment: No If you made that then other users along with user1 and user2 all other users like user3,4.....n and any other can access that data and that is a security risk.